# Performance difference between SELECT and DELETE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I recently observe a behavior with PostgreSQL db v12.5. And want to understand the root cause in behind.

`table_a` is with around 6M records.

DELETE with poor performance **(takes 10+ mins)**

```
DELETE FROM table_a 
WHERE key = '123' 
  AND month = ANY(SELECT TO_CHAR(generate_series, 'YYYY-MM') 
                  FROM GENERATE_SERIES(NOW() - interval '2 month', NOW(), interval '1'));
```

DELETE with better performance (takes 1.7 seconds)

```
DELETE FROM table_a 
WHERE key = '123' 
  AND month IN (SELECT month IN time_bucket);
```

SELECT with poor performance (takes 6 seconds)

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_a 
WHERE key = '123' 
  AND month = ANY(SELECT TO_CHAR(generate_series, 'YYYY-MM') 
                  FROM GENERATE_SERIES(NOW() - interval '2 month', NOW(), interval '1'));
```

SELECT with better performance (takes 1.3 seconds)

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_a 
WHERE key = '123' 
  AND month IN (SELECT month IN time_bucket);
```

I understand DELETE is usually slower than SELECT. My key question is in my case, with same poor query condition, why it could make DELETE super slow, but make less effect on SELECT.

The DELETE PLAN with poor performance is as below

```
                                                                   QUERY PLAN                                                                   
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Delete on table_a  (cost=12.51..982166.00 rows=534 width=38) (actual time=72475.407..72475.410 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=12.51..982166.00 rows=534 width=38) (actual time=9704.336..9719.715 rows=120 loops=1)
         Join Filter: (table_a.month = to_char(generate_series.generate_series, 'YYYY-MM'::text))
         Rows Removed by Join Filter: 600
         ->  HashAggregate  (cost=12.51..14.51 rows=200 width=40) (actual time=4810.752..4810.764 rows=3 loops=1)
               Group Key: to_char(generate_series.generate_series, 'YYYY-MM'::text)
               ->  Function Scan on generate_series  (cost=0.01..10.01 rows=1000 width=40) (actual time=761.268..3863.142 rows=5270401 loops=1)
         ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..978419.66 rows=1067 width=14) (actual time=94.432..1636.150 rows=240 loops=3)
               ->  Seq Scan on table_a  (cost=0.00..978414.32 rows=1067 width=14) (actual time=283.269..4908.276 rows=240 loops=1)
                     Filter: (key = '123'::text)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 6129200
Planning Time: 0.175 ms
JIT:
   Functions: 18
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 2.372 ms, Inlining 9.279 ms, Optimization 83.968 ms, Emission 50.601 ms, Total 146.220 ms
Execution Time: 72504.330 ms
```

Comment: Do you have an index on `(key, month)`? What data type are those two columnsß

Comment: The first query is slow because you are generating one row per second for those three months which results in more than 5 million rows - but you only want 3 rows (=months). You should use `interval '1 month` for the increment in `generate_series()`

Comment: Could you share the results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for these statements? (this will execute the DELETE statement, be aware)

Comment: Hi I understand the first query is slow. I also know how to improve the performance with EXPLAIN.  My question is with such awful condition (ANY....). Why it makes bigger impact in DELETE SQL than in SELECT SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Common `DELETE` performance problem is missing indexes on foreign keys. Then the check of ref integrity is slow. You can run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` command, where you can see the overhead of some parts.